# Чому в одному випадку люди обирають запозичене слово, а в іншому вигадують власне?

Tags: linguistics, соціолінгвістика

Чи є якісь дослідження, що розглядають процес утворення нових слів в українській мові, порівняно з процесом запозичення. Йдеться про те, в яких випадках слово буде запозичене, термін перекладуть або ж спільнота, що  потребує цього слова, створить своє власне нове. Які чинники на це впливають? Наприклад, серед тих, що я знайшла, називають: слово коротше, слово легше вимовляти або ж легше змінювати, згідно правил мови. Чи є розділ лінгвістики, що це вивчає?

**UPD:** Здається, що питання написане не зовсім зрозуміло, тому додам пояснення. Це питання не про те, як комісії або інститути вигадують нові слова чи терміни. Мене цікавить, що робить слово привабливим для людей. Чому в одному випадку люди обирають запозичене слово, а в іншому вигадують власне. Я думаю, що якщо проаналізувати певну кількість випадків, то можна знайти якісь закономірності. Ще додам, що цей процес може йти всупереч інститутам і комісіям, коли комісія вибрала один термін, а люди все одно кажуть щось інше, бо термін їм не подобається.

Comment: не зовсім дубль, але дуже схоже на http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/94/%D0%A7%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%96-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%96-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%8E

Comment: Яким чином тоді це питання стосується саме української мови? Адже процес запозичення відбувається в усіх мовах. Наразі це виглядає як off-topic

Comment: Це питання стосується *саме* процесу запозичення в українській мові, з конкретними прикладами, виведеними тенденціями тощо.

Comment: @NashBridges Я думаю що обговорення явищ, які є і в інших мовах не є офтопіком доки питання не потребує широкого залучення матеріалу з інших мов. Наприклад детального порівняння синтаксичних структур української і турецької мови, чи щось типу "які українські слова потрапили у французьку мову" - тут не очікується наявність експертів з франзузької, і тому це офтопік. А інакше ми будемо обмежені тільки укр. лексикою - навіть структура речення є дуже подібною у інших мовах, що ж ми про неї не можемо поговорити?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Наскільки мені відомо, лінгвістика ще не дійшла до такого рівня щоб передбачувати розвиток мови наперед, тобто вона не може розрахувати вірогідність введення нового слова і яке саме слово буде взято суспільством. Чи досягне вона такого рівня - також не відомо.

Тепер щодо того про що можна сказати.

Потреба у новому слові може бути: через суспільні зміни, через появу нових явищ/предметів, потребу нових смислів.

В залежності від того що є джерелом такої новизни - україномовне суспільство чи іншомовне слово буде а) створено засоби української мови; б) слово буде запозичено (можливо тільки на короткий час) з тієї культури, звідки прийшло це явище. Причому це запозичення не обов'язково означає те саме явище у мові-джерелі.

> Наприклад слово кілер. Запозичено з англійської, де означає "вбивця" (вбив кота - вже "кілер"). У нас означає "найманий вбивця" і саме через це нове для 90-х років поняття воно було запозичене з "іноземної культури".

Далі запозичене слово починає змінюватися згідно фонетичних і інших правил української мови. Через декілька років стає зрозуміло - чи воно прижилося чи ні. Чи сприймається воно суспільством, чи кожен носій намагається його калькувати чи перекладати власне українською.

> Наприклад слово раlеtоt "пальто" має у французькій мові чоловічий рід, але через закінчення -о набуло середнього роду в українській.

Навіть коли слово прижилося, через деякий час воно може випасти з ужитку (наприклад через зміни у моді і т.і.), або його новий вузький зміст буде включений у вже старе слово, яке має більш ширший зміст.

> Наприклад слово ґламур - деякий час було дуже популярним, а зараз вживається набагато рідше. Але воно зробило важливий внесок - ідею "краси у повсякденному житті".

Comment: певні передбачення щодо майбутнього нерегулярних дієслів в англійській мові все ж таки були зроблені ще у 2007: [Mathematicians apply evolutionary models to linguistic standardization](http://news.harvard.edu/gazette/story/2007/10/harvard-scientists-predict-the-future-of-the-past-tense/). Це звісно вирішення протилежної задачі і показує які слова скоріше за все вимруть. Але ідея застосування еволюційного підходу може мати певні плоди, хоча б і науково-фантастичні

Comment: @Chizh Наскільки я зрозумів у 2007 році порахували швидкість переходу нерегулярних дієслів до регулярної групи. Вони не передбачили сам цей процес - він відомий вже давно. Причому слова, що використовуються дуже часто мають дуже малі шанси змінити тип зміни. Такі слова це "бути" be/was/were/been та "іти" go/went/gone. Але еволюційні паралелі у розвитку мови звичайно є. І знов ж таки - у біології також не можна зазирнути у майбутнє біосфери з тих самих причин - певні закономірності розвитку існують, але поява нових явищ - процес хаотичний і непередбачуваний.

Comment: саме так, але можна виявити та, можливо, передбачити екологічні ниші, які визначають функцію та певним чином оптимальну форму, що може звузити поле можливих варіантів, серед яких і буде проходити подальша селекція. а це вже не мало у порівнянні з первістним хаосом

Comment: Передбачення - це складніша задача, а от аналіз вже існуючих слів, мабуть, заробити можна. Цікаво було б подивитися не лише конкретні приклади, а й глобально: як розвивалася мова в контексті запозичень / свого власного, які тенденції було знайдено, які припущення зробили дослідники, чому воно саме так. Але, думаю, Ваша відповідь на разі найкраще відповідає питанню