# Чи всі терміни мають бути перекладені українською?

Tags: запозичені-слова

Багато з останніх питань тут були про варіянти перекладу тих чи инших термінів, source code, тенісні терміни, rebate, desktop application, default value, тощо.

Але для чого це? Чи можете ви пояснити та обґрунтувати необхідність перекладу цих термінів українською? Сприймайте це питання як можливість у відповідях пояснити необхідність перекладу вашого терміну, як противагу його входженню в українську мову в іноземній формі.

Для довідки нагадаю, що в таку потужну мову, як японська, всі ці терміни увійшли в їхніх англійських формах, більше того, близько 90% всього словникового запасу японської мови складають запозичені слова, в основному, — з китайської. В англійській мові доля запозичених слів (тобто не англо-саксонських) складає близько 70%. Що товариство скаже на це?

Comment: @Artemix очевидний одрук. Мусило напевно бути [Ергативна](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%96_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8) структура мови (2 з 3 слів - запозичені :) )

Comment: @Artemix - А [оце що](http://tapemark.narod.ru/les/593b.html)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Я думаю що зараз найбільший тиск щодо перекладу термінів українською йде від стандартів оформлення документації. Ці стандарти склалися ще за часів СРСР, коли всі терміни повинні були перекладатися (ЕОМ замість комп'ютер, КД-ПЗП замість CD-ROM і т.і.).

Колись така ж політика була у великих виробників програмного забезпечення (Майкрософт), які перекладали документацію для користувачів. Так з'явився "клік мишею", "додатки" і т.і.

Сучасна документація комерційних продуктів для кінцевих споживачів спрощується і орієнтується на слова які на думку авторів вже відомі користувачу - і тут взагалі немає обмежень.

Але залишається документація для різних офіційних установ (державних організацій), де "баттони" і "дефолтні параметри" можуть сприйматися неадекватно замовником. Як раз така документація дуже консервативна і зберігає всю перекладену термінологію і можливо спонукає її авторів для перекладання нових термінів, яких не було за часи СРСР.

Наостанок цитата з документації 15-річної давнини (цей пасаж зустрічався по декілька разів на сторінку): "Подальший свій вибір користувач реалізує за допомогою подвійного натискання лівої кнопки маніпулятору "миша".

Моя думка така: чим більше у офіційних установах буде людей з покоління що звикло до комп'ютера, тим менше буде попит на переклад всіх іноземних IT-термінів українською.

Comment: А вам не здається диким начебто український текст на кшталт "Юзер клікає мишкою по батону, встановлює дефолтні вел'юз для сеттингів і переходить до наступного скріна"? Це вже виходить (принаймні з лексичної точки зору) абсолютно неукраїнський текст, а просто українізована транскрипція англійського тексту. В чому користь від такого "перекладу"? Чи не простіше тоді просто всім користуватися англійською?

Comment: Я не кажу що "батон" це гарний переклад. Він не може бути гарним за означенням, бо співпадає з назвою хліба. Це був приклад того що комерційні компанії не мають жодних обмежень у використанні лексики. Якщо їх аудиторія - підлітки, використання сленгу може бути для компанії зручною. Моя думка у тому що мова (якщо вона жива) відбере сама найзручніший термін - чи перекладений, чи запозичений. Звичайно щоб це відбулося треба мати з чого вибирати, але ніколи не можна бути певним що логічний і семантично зважений переклад закріпиться у мовній практиці.

Comment: @Maksym, Re: *«Юзер клікає мишкою по батону, встановлює дефолтні вел'юз…»* — не бачу нічого поганого. :) Наприклад, *«Парламент ратифікує конвенцію про квоти на використання нітратів в агропромисловому комплексі»*.

Comment: @bytebuster а ще і таке буває: «вайтові трузера на зіперах з файновми лейблом на лефтовому покеті». гадаю це лиш говорить про нестачу творчих сил для віднайдення/винайдення досдойних відповідників.

Answer (score 12):

На мою думку користувача термінології тут має вирішувати фонетика - якщо запозичений термін "вписується" в усталену фонетику мови то можна залишити як є, якщо ж він звучить незграбно то краще буде його перекласти. Ну і навпаки

Comment: Я теж так вважаю. Наприклад, моє питання щодо Rebate. Якщо записати фонетично, то виходить незграбно і важко для написання і прочитування  (рабат, ребейт, рібейт, тощо), а от варіант ретро-бонус, вже звучить непагано, хоча і складається з запозичених слів (ретро (лат.) і бонус (лат.))

Answer (score 11):

Головним завданням локалізації іноземних термінів є допомога *мовній людині підсвідомо краще розуміти такі терміни. Чим більше термінів вписуватиметься в мовну матрицю людини зі зрозумілими для неї сенсами, тим швидше людина буде своєю мовою розуміти світ.

Іноді немає нормального відповідника іноземному слову. В такому випадку немає сенсу змушувати себе казати якесь неоковирне слово.

Тобто, ці відповідники треба шукати і намагатися інтеґрувати їх в свою мову (таким чином зберігаючи мовну самобутність), але при цьому не можна займатися лінґвістичним насильством і перероблювати навіть те, що очевидно не надається до мовної локалізації.

До речі, є сайт [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/), на якому люди разом шукають відповідники до іноземних термінів і кальки з російської.

Comment: Ба більше. Інколи _неосмислене_ запозичення надалі призводить до зовсім хибних новоутворень. До прикладу, "businessman" у нас став "бізнесменом", але замість фемінітиву "businesswoman" з'являється…"бізнесменка" (і справа тут не в простонародності, "бізнесмужичка" — так би українською ніхто не сказав)!

Answer (score 4):

Як на мене, то ні. Не завжди український відповідник передає суть поняття як такого.

До прикладу, візьмемо економічний термін "indifference curves".
Існують два відповідники цього словосполучення: "криві байдужості" або "криві індиферентності". По суті, то є криві, що відображають різні набори товарів, які приносять однакове задоволення споживачеві, а тому нічого спільного з байдужістю вони не мають.

Comment: А якщо перекласти як *криві незначності*, тобто криві коли для пацієнта вже немає значення? Гадаю, просто варто шукати якісний відповідник.