# "Geek" - ґік чи дивак?

Tags: переклад, from-english

Перекладачі все частіше і частіше стикаються з англійськими словами, які інколи неможливо пояснити, використавши лише одне українське слово.

Слово "geek" у Сучасному англо-українському словнику (автори: В. Мюллер, М. Зубков, В. Федієнко) має таке визначення як "дивак" чи навіть "дурень", однак зараз в англомовних країнах, зокрема в Америці, воно вживається в значенні "а knowledgeable and obsessive enthusiast", тобто це людина, яка чимось дуже цікавиться, наприклад комп'ютерними іграми, фільмами, тощо (визначення взяті з [Оксфордського словника](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/)).

Отож, чи є в українській мові якийсь наш відповідник (адже ви розумієте, що слова "дурень" чи "дивак" не підійдуть для створення адекватного перекладу, а варіанти з онлайн перекладачів (прекладач "Мета", ГуглПерекладач, тощо) - "комп'ютерщик" чи "виродок" не завжди підходить за змістом)? Чи все ж таки краще зробити транслітерацію і перекласти його як "гік"?

Comment: Сучасний англо-український словник - назва словника, книга, де зібрані всі сучасні слова англійської мови. Його не можна вважати за джерело?

Comment: Коментарі видаляються. Мінус перетворюється на плюс. Дуже дякую.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 1. Все залежить від контексту.

[Oxford Dictionaries for "geek":](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/geek)

> 1. An unfashionable or socially inept person.
>
> 1.1 [**usually with modifier**] A knowledgeable and obsessive enthusiast. ‘a **computer** geek’.

Для першого значення маємо відповідну статтю у [Англійсько-українських словниках](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=geek&dicts=all&highlight=on):

> 1) (ексцентрична або неприваблива людина, особливо з інтелектом)
>   ексце́нтрик, ентузіа́ст, фана́т; ґік;

Обирайте з цього ряду те слово, яке вам у тій чи іншій ситуації підходить найкраще.

Для другого краще використовувати транслітерацію, бо це міжнародний термін на позначення людини, що є фанатично, обсесивно занурена у певну діяльність (вже навіть маємо [статтю на вікі](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%96%D0%BA_(%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0)) та україномовний ютуб-канал "ґік джорнал" (не подаю тут посилання, щоби не вважали за рекламу абощо). Також можемо подивитися результати в ґуґлі, для [слова "ґік" вже є](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%22%D2%91%D1%96%D0%BA%22&source=lnt&tbs=lr:lang_1uk&lr=lang_uk&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9h_KJuYraAhXCjCwKHTUSA4gQpwUIHw&biw=1366&bih=662) 5,5 тисяч результатів українською мовою + [11 тис](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%22%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%BA%22&source=lnt&tbs=lr:lang_1uk&lr=lang_uk&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjT_oW4uYraAhVBkSwKHS4jCGkQpwUIHw&biw=1366&bih=662) для неправильної транслітерації.

#### 2. [Транслітерація](http://zakon4.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/55-2010-%D0%BF/conv).

> Ґґ |Gg |Ґалаґан |Galagan |Ґорґани |Gorgany

Літера "Gg" передається через літеру "Ґґ", отже, не гік, а **ґ**ік.

До того ж, дивіться відповіді на схожі питання:

[Правила вживання букв г/х при перекладі іншомовних термінів (гакер, гостинг)](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/347/240)

#### 3. [Ініціатива перекладу іншомовних слів.](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/gik)

На словотворі іноді є хороші питомі відповідники на іншомовні слова, але цього разу думаю, варто утриматися від використання варіантів, що їх запропонували користувачі, бо всі відповідники не надто відповідають тим значенням, які нас цікавлять.

До того ж, дивіться відповіді на схожі питання:

[Чи всі терміни мають бути перекладені українською?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/94/240)