# Чи варто перекладати слово "лайк" українською?

Tags: вживання-слів

Знайшла в мережі різні варіанти слова "лайк": вподобайка, любчик, мені подобається, вподоба, вподобка, добрик, плюсик.

Більшість з них - слова, які запропонували користувачі мережі. Яке ж слово доречно вживати? Лайк чи інше? Інформацію з приводу цього питання я не знайшла.

Comment: Варто чи не варто — залежить як від контексту (який не вказано), так і від субʼєктивних уподобань. Будь ласка, уточніть запитання.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Чи всі терміни мають бути перекладені українською?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/94/%d0%a7%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%96-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%96%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%96-%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%97%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%8e)

Answer (score 4):

[Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/laik) дає такий варіант як "вподобайка", з яким я також погоджуюся, адже дієслово "to like" означає "подобатися" або "вподобати" (Гугл Перекладач), а тому іменник "like" буде доречно перекласти як "вподобайка". На сайті ["Народного перекладу"](http://www.kray.ck.ua/kultura/mova/item/11582-narodniy-pereklad-inshomovnih-sliv-ukrayinskoyu#.WuQmn3-YPIU) є ще такі варіанти як "уподобайка" та "плюсик".

Comment: А от як так само добре перекласти `dislike`?

Answer (score 3):

В СУМ-20 вже присутне слово ***"лайк"***, тому  можемо його використовувати, але не в офіційних документах, оскільки є примітка *"жаргоне"*.

> **[Лайк](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=218624&page=1471)**  *у, ч., жарг.* Спосіб схвалення користувачем Інтернету матеріалу, профілю користувача, фотографії і т. ін. через клік чи
>   натискання функціональної кнопки (використовується перев. у соціальних
>   мережах). *Журналіст отримав 23 місяці умовно за лайк під коментарем
>   із критикою турецького президента* (із журн.); *Лайк та репост цього
>   матеріалу в соціальних мережах дає можливість виграти три місяці
>   безкоштовного хостингу* (з Інтернету).