# Як нові слова стають частиною української мови?

Tags: неологізми, language-regulation

Не до кінця розумію процес додавання нових слів в українській мові. Логіка підказує, що слово стає частиною мови, коли його додають у словник, який видається уповноваженою організацією/інститутом.

Для англійської мови [знайшов таке](http://enlizza.com/%D1%8F%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%8C/):

> Головними ресурсами є Oxford English Corpus і Oxford Reading
>   Programme. Перше джерело містить велику кількість текстів, зібраних на
>   просторах Інтернету, а другий — електронну колекцію пропозицій або
>   маленьких уривків текстів абсолютно різних стилів: від текстів пісень
>   до матеріалів з наукових журналів.
>
> Працівники видавництва постійно відстежують ці два ресурси на предмет
>   наявності нових слів. Якщо вони бачать, що нове слово або термін
>   з’являється досить часто в абсолютно різних контекстах, поняття стає
>   кандидатом на додавання в якійсь із Оксфордських словників. У підсумку
>   вибираються саме ті слова, які вважаються найбільш значимими і
>   важливими, які залишаться в мові на довгий час.

Частково, на це питання дають відповідь [тут](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/16/584), [тут](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/153/584) і [тут](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/229/what-is-an-authoritative-source-for-neologisms-in-ukrainian), однак мене цікавить, **чи існує якийсь формалізований процес, критерії, терміни як вибираються слова, що стають кандидатами на додавання?**

Answer (score 5):

[Тут](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/229/what-is-an-authoritative-source-for-neologisms-in-ukrainian) відповіли, що напевне, на найбільш офіційному рівні таким займається [Інститут української мови НАНУ](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%86%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%83%D1%82_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8_%D0%9D%D0%90%D0%9D_%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B8), де укладали  словник «[Нові слова та значення](https://books.google.com.ua/books/about/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D1%82%D0%B0_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD.html?hl=uk&id=ww0qAQAAIAAJ)» (2009).

У статті «[Засади створення словника нових слів та значень](http://bo0k.net/index.php?p=achapter&bid=20245&chapter=1)» сказано таке:

> … фіксація нових термінів відбувається з урахуванням кількох критеріїв:
>   час появи, зумовленість (мовна чи позамовна), вживання та словотвірне
>   значення. Словник має на меті засвідчити нові слова та значення для
>   дослідження майбутнього входження їх у мову. Оскільки нові слова в
>   українській мові правописно неусталені, словник не претендує на
>   нормативність.
>
> До словника не включено індивідуальні авторські новотвори, експресивно
>   забарвлені слова; назви медичних препаратів та засобів гігієни … патронімічні назви та номенклатура продуктів … .

У «Лексикографічному бюлетені» часом друкують матеріали до словників, наприклад у [випуску 18](http://www1.nas.gov.ua/institutes/ium/lb/Documents/LB-18.pdf)) є стаття «Матеріали до словника нових слів і значень (слова з прикладкою інтернет)», які увійшли до згаданого, а у випуску 20 є стаття з [матеріалами](http://dspace.nbuv.gov.ua/bitstream/handle/123456789/73232/28-Gabai.pdf) до «Словника граматичного керування прикметників», тощо. Тобто слово проходить стадії вживання в пресі — вживання у наукових публікаціях і тематичних словниках — внесення у словник загальний.

У 2010 опубліковано «[Нові й актуалізовані слова та значення. Словникові матеріали 1 (2002–2010)](https://krytyka.com/ua/reviews/novi-y-aktualizovani-slova-ta-znachennya-slovnykovi-materialy-1-2002-2010)», і було [заплановано](http://dspace.nbuv.gov.ua/bitstream/handle/123456789/43665/04-Lozova.pdf) створювати щорічники нових слів у формі тлумачних праць з вибірковим дослідженням джерел, однак на цей момент я не спостерігаю в інтернеті свідчень їх існування.

Обов'язково треба пам'ятати й про те, що

> брак слова у наявних словниках не є свідченням його відсутности в
>   живій чи фаховій мові, це лише свідчення того, що наявні словники його
>   не зафіксували ([джерело](http://r2u.org.ua/node/271))

А ще є публікації де [ганять](http://ekmair.ukma.edu.ua/bitstream/handle/123456789/1939/Klymenko_Literaturna_norma.pdf) словникарів, які допускають різне написання однотипних запозичень (на прикладі *боді-пірсинг* і *бодібілдинг*), чим підводять читача до думки, що потрапляння у словник — не останній етап розвитку неологізма.

Comment: Від себе додам, що не уявляю формалізованого процесу визначення того, чи слово існує, чи ні. Зважаючи на потоп інформації, неможливо визначити, скільки разів слово було вжите, всерйоз чи як спроба, і тим більше, зробити це так-сяк оперативно. Слова виникають щодня, і вони справді існують, навіть якщо життєвий цикл їхній складає два дні. Неправильні (хибно утворені чи потрактовані) слова також існують, але не вносяться в словники, аби не заохочувати людей до їх вживання, коли є адекватні відповідники. Все, що треба мовцеві, це трохи мовної гігієни, яка приходить з читанням.